# Ubuntu 18.04 huge battery drain from network interfaces wlp3s0 (iwlwifi)

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, power-management, battery

Im quite new to linux. I bought a new laptop (Aero 15x w/ Intel 7th gen and GTX 1070 MaxQ) and made a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install.
Now I was trying to increase battery life as i get just around 3 hours or so, compared to ~7 on Windows.

I have TLP and Powertop and what I have found in Powertop is, that the network interfaces wlp3s0 (iwlwifi) drains around 14W which cannot be true.

I tried to look it up and just found https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2551533 with the same problem but no solution. The people there were just talking that it is impossible for a wifi card to use so much power, so I would also guess that it is something with the nvidia gpu.

I run the 390.48, 4.15.0-20-generic driver and have nvidia prime installed but it is actually set to the Intel gpu.

Would really appreciate any help bc I dont want to use Windows but right now Ubuntu makes it really difficult for me.

Cheers

PS: Im happy to give more information if needed.

EDIT:
I found that this is a known bug in 18.04, that the eGPU does not turn off. It is already on Lauchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1765363
Should I keep my post here or delete it?

Comment: try installing laptop-mode-tools

Comment: from reading that link, the noveau driver fixed it for someone.  Hit alt+f1 and search for updates. Click on Software & Updates and under additional drivers select the noveau driver. if things work better with noveau... install the proprietary driver per this howto http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux once you finish with step three run software and updates and install the recommended driver there.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The problem is that when i change to the noveau driver and reboot and check in software and updates which driver is in use it is greyed out and has a new point which is activated and says contiune using manually installed driver. when checking with lshw -c video, i see that for the nvidia card it says noveua and for the intel i915. The problem is, that the battery drain is still the same in powertop.

Comment: Through this post I found about the bug you linked to (thank you!). So I think it's useful to others who might stumble upon it as well and you should probably keep it. Maybe add your own last edit as an answer because it's a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I found that this is a known bug in 18.04, that the eGPU does not turn off. It is already on Lauchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1765363 Should I keep my post here or delete it?

There exists a workaround: https://github.com/timrichardson/Prime-Ubuntu-18.04

But I hope that they will change it again in the next version of Ubuntu as it worked just fine before 18.04

EDIT November 2018: I did a clean reinstall of Ubuntu 18.10 and now everything works fine. Switching between Intel and NVidia GPU is working.